# File Locking in AccuRev

Tags: accurev

I need to lock a single file in AccuRev to avoid modification in the file by anyone. I know there is one way is to achieve it through AccuRev trigger. But I can't go with trigger because of the following:

1) Our AccuRev is on client side and used by many teams and therefore can't ask for server level trigger.

2) For client level trigger I need to ask put the script on all client machines or at some shared location.

Is there any other ways to achieve this easily in AccuRev?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Element-Level Security (EACLs)

Look in the admin manual under section "Element-Level Security (EACLs)".

Here is a link to a training video.

http://www.accurev.com/customer-support-resources/elearning-video-center

See the " Introduction to Element Access Controls (EACLs)" video.